# merging the lines of a sqlite query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

i have the following rows in my table irrigation:

```
CodeIrrigation |CodeSecteur|Date_Irrigation | Cubage |
---------------|-----------|----------------|--------| 
     1         |    2      | 12/04/2012     | 1300   |
---------------|-----------|----------------|--------|
     2         |    3      | 12/04/2012     | 1500   |
---------------|-----------|----------------|--------|
```

what i want as result is:

```
    CodeIrrigation |CodeSecteur1|CodeSecteur2|Date_Irrigation | 
    ---------------|------------|------------|----------------| 
         1         |    2       |    3       | 12/04/2012     |
```

is there a query that can return something like that?

Comment: Are you using Sqlite, MySQL or SQL Server? Or all three? Can you please only tag the RDBMS you're actually using?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on SO doing this very thing. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255640/mysql-reshape-data-from-long-tall-to-wide). You can search the site for "pivot"/"unpivot" and it should get you the info you need.

Comment: And how are you correlating the rows?  Is it only by date (and that name probably ought to be something like `irrigatedOn`, columns shouldn't be prefixed with type)?  Do you know roughly how many pivoted columns you're going to need?

Comment: @X-Zero the culumns are grouped just by date and i'm going to need CodeIrrigation1,CodeIrrigation2,CodeSecteur1,CodeSecteur2 and  of course the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CodeIrrigation) AS 'CodeIrrigation', 
    MIN(CodeSecteur) AS 'CodeSecteur1', 
    MAX(CodeSecteur) AS 'CodeSecteur2'
FROM table
GROUP BY Date_Irrigation
```

Comment: nice it's working tahnks but how about if i want to add another column? for example CodeIrrigation1 and CodeIrrigation2?

Comment: @cascadox, If these values are limited like in your example, then you have to add it e.g. `MIN(CodeIrrigation) as CodeIrrigation1, MAX(CodeIrrigation) AS CodeIrrigation1`. Bear in mind the `GROUP BY` clause. If these values are not countable and you need to do this dynamically then you have to do this with dynamic sql if you are using SQL Server.