# How to Unstack Time Series Data into Columns in MyS

Tags: mysql

I have a table is SQL similar to below:

| Date | ticker | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 100 |
| 2 | X | 101 |
| 3 | X | 102 |
| 1 | Y | 50 |
| 2 | Y | 51 |
| 3 | Y | 52 |

and would like to change it to the following table

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 101 | 51 |
| 3 | 102 | 52 |

I know this can be done using Unstack in pandas, but I am not sure how to do this in MySQL. Also, I need to assign the column headings dynamically, since I have hundreds of tickers (X, Y, Z, ...).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql, reshape data from long / tall to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255640/mysql-reshape-data-from-long-tall-to-wide)

Comment: [SO: mysql long to wide](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+long+to+wide+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk002qPqW6VmV3OjI7SFqxhEPAiTjHg:1628794746641&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh4qOilazyAhXHEzQIHSg2DnsQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=918) & [dba: mysql long to wide](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+long+to+wide+site:dba.stackexchange.com&sxsrf=ALeKk002qPqW6VmV3OjI7SFqxhEPAiTjHg:1628794746641&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh4qOilazyAhXHEzQIHSg2DnsQrQIoA3oECAYQBA&biw=1920&bih=918)

Comment: As an FYI, SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: @ Trenton... there are two suggested answers in the link, but they both rely on me specifying the new table's column headings. I need a solution where column headings are automatically generated from the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet on a similar data that seems to work for my scenario. The values get altered a bit for me for some reason, but if I round them, they approach the original values.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists Meeting
(
ID INT,
Meeting_id INT,
field_key VARCHAR(100),
field_value VARCHAR(100)
);
```

INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (1, 1,'first_name' , John);
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (2, 1,'last_name' , 'Jones');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (3, 1,'occupation' , 'engineer');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (4,2,'first_name' , Jack);
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (5,2,'last_name' , 'Doe');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (6,2,'occupation' , 'engineer');

select * from meeting;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'max(case when field_key = ''',
field_key,
''' then field_value end) ',
field_key
)
) INTO @sql
FROM
Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Meeting_id, ', @sql, '
FROM Meeting
GROUP BY Meeting_id');

```
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: (4,2,'first_name' , Jack)