# In Snowflake, how do I parse an unnamed JSON array and access each key with key value rather than array slicing methods?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON array in Snowflake, where I need to parse into a table, i.e., convert all information into a row. Assume my table includes two columns: id and json_tag column.

An example row is as below:

```
{ [
json_tag

[
  {
    "key": "app.name",
    "value": "myapp1"
  },
  {
    "key": "device.name",
    "value": "myiPhone11"
  },
  {
    "key": "iOS.dist",
    "value": "latestDist5"
  }
]
```

This is not a standard example, another example can have 5 or even 6 with new key names. An example is below:

```
{ [
json_tag

[
  {
    "key": "app.name",
    "value": "myapp2"
  },
  {
    "key": "app.cost",
    "value": "$2.99"
  },
  {
    "key": "device.name",
    "value": "myiPhoneX"
  },
  {
    "key": "device.color",
    "value": "gold"
  },
  {
    "key": "iOS.dist",
    "value": "latestDist4.9"
  }
]
```

What I want is working on a table (without creating a new one) where the json row is split into columns as below:

```
id app.name app.cost device.name device.color iOS.dist 
1  myapp1   null     myiPhone11  null         latestDist5
2  myapp2   $2.99    myiPhoneX   gold         latestDist4.9
```

I tried the following snippet:

```
with parsed_tb as (
    select id, 
           to_variant(parse_json(json_tag)) as parsed_json_tag
    from mytable
)



 select parsed_json_tag[0]:value::varchar as app_name, 
        parsed_json_tag[1]:value::varchar as app_cost, 
        parsed_json_tag[2]:value::varchar as device_name
 from tb;
```

As you can imagine, the snippet above does not work when there is no app.cost in key values or every row differs in number of keys and values.

I tried `lateral flatten` command in Snowflake, but out creates many rows and I cannot figure out how to put them in columns in the same row. I also tried using `recursive` command, and could not achieve it.

So my question is:

1. How can I access a key by its name rather than slicing an array as I do above? - this would solve my problem I guess.
2. If #1 solution I imagine does not fix, how can I attain the table above?

Comment: Is that a valid JSON sample?

Comment: @Mova yes it is a valid sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem with the help of following thread:

[Mysql, reshape data from long / tall to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255640/mysql-reshape-data-from-long-tall-to-wide)

Solution is first parsing json column with unique identifier, and then lateral flattening and then grouping the results by unique identifier [formatting table from long to wide as given in the link above].

So for the examples I provided above, the solution would be as follows:

```
with tb as (
     select id, 
            to_variant(parse_json(json_tags)) as parsed_json_tags
     from mytable
), 

flattened as (
     select id,
            VALUE:value::string as value, 
            VALUE:key::string as key
     from mytable, lateral flatten(input => (tb.parsed_json_tags))
)

select id, 
       MAX( IFF( key='app.name', value, NULL ) ) AS app_name,
       MAX( IFF( key='app.cost', value, NULL ) ) AS app_cost,
       MAX( IFF( key='device.name', value, NULL ) ) AS device_name,
       MAX( IFF( key='device.color', value, NULL ) ) AS device_color,
       MAX( IFF( key='iOS.dist', value, NULL ) ) AS ios_dist

from flattened
group by 1;
```